# Prove using gaussian elimination that the linear system Ax =B has a unique solution....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

... and also show that the least square solution is the same, explain why this is the case.

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -3 & 1 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ b = \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

so i used gaussian elimination to determine the solutions and got these values x = 1, y = 0, z = 3

then i used the least square solution method to find the solutions. and i got the same values.

But why did i get the same values?

Can someone help me understand why i got the same values when i used the least square solution method to find the solutions to Ax = B?

Comment: Since $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, the system is not inconsistent, and therefore the least squares solution will be identical (since there is no error on the approximate solution)

Answer (score 0):

writing 
$$x_1+2x_2+x_3=4$$
$$2x_1+4x_2+x_3=5$$
$$3x_1-3x_2+x_3=6$$
multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the second we get
$$-x_3=-3$$
myltiplying the first by $-3$ and adding to the third we get
$$-9x_2-2x_3=-6$$
with $$x_3=3$$ we obtaine
$$-9x_2-6=-6$$
can you finish?
and with $x_2=0,x_3=3$ we get $$3x_1+3=6$$ therefore $$x_1=1$$